# Scalling CSS for other monitors

Tags: html, css

My website is positioned perfectly for me but not for my larger monitor. The div's are more compact on the larger monitor and incorrect. How can I fix this?

Comment: We're going to need some code snippets (not a code dump) to see what you're talking about. Please include a link to the website, or a repo containing minimal code to show the problem.

Comment: Please people, stop answering this question. You are just speculating.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe that you have problems because you hard-coded the sizes.

I'd suggest you to use relative sizes, e.g.:

```
#el{
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
```

In the above example, an element with `id = "el"` will have  width which will be half the width of the window and the height of this element will be equal to the height of window (unless this element is located in another element, the width and height of which is less than 100%).

Comment: Yes, i was using px. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use media query for responsive. if you used it, may be your meta tag is not working correctly.

below the examples are.....

```
@media screen and (min-width:00px) and (max-width:00px){
     /*extra style will goes here. 
}
```

Don't forget to use this `<meta .../>` tag on `<head></head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```